# Manually Add Header in CsvHelper.CsvWriter

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm using `CsvHelper` class to write rows in `DataTable` to a csv file. The code works but I can't get it to write the headers.

How can I add the headers manually without creating a Class Map?

http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

```
DataTable dt = GetDataTableFromDB();

System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter( memoryStream );
CsvHelper.CsvWriter writer = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter( streamWriter );

foreach ( DataColumn column in properties.Columns )
    writer.WriteHeader( column.ColumnName );    //<--- How do I write to column

foreach ( DataRow row in dt.Rows )
{
    foreach ( object item in row.ItemArray )
        writer.WriteField( item.ToString() );

    writer.NextRecord();
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update:**

`DataTable` functionality is built in now. https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/data-table

**Original:**

This is actually in the [documentation](http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#misc-faq) under `Writing to a CSV using a DataTable`.

I'll put the code example here too.

```
using( var dt = new DataTable() )
{
    dt.Load( dataReader );
    foreach( DataColumn column in dt.Columns )
    {
        csv.WriteField( column.ColumnName );
    }
    csv.NextRecord();

    foreach( DataRow row in dt.Rows )
    {
        for( var i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++ )
        {
            csv.WriteField( row[i] );
        }
        csv.NextRecord();
    }
}
```

Headers aren't anything special or different in a CSV file.

Comment: I'd like to use this method, but have never used a ``datareader``. Where can I find out how to populate a new datatable from an existing datatable?

Comment: "Headers aren't anything special or different in a CSV file." This is true- but then why do you have an API called `WriteHeader()`? Maybe it should have an overload that accepts an `Enumerable<string>`.

Comment: Actually, the referenced documentation for writing to a CSV using a DataTable was omitted in the new documentation. There are some comments by the library author in tracked [issue #1399](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1399).

Comment: `DataTable` functionality is built in now. https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/data-table

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any documentation concerning DataTables any more

Answer (score 16):

The easiest way is to use

```
writer.WriteHeader<YourClass>();
```

More complete example:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\output.csv"))
{
  using (CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(sw))
  {
     writer.WriteHeader<YourClass>();
     writer.NextRecord();
     writer.WriteRecord(yourRecordVariable);
  }
}
```

As was posted [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/csvhelper/qrXjTawkyCQ) on Google groups by the author Josh Close.

Comment: I needed to add  `writer.NextRecord();` after writing the header to have a line break.