# Why is CsvHelper getting header missing error?

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I want to save a List with headers to a csv file, and then read it back in.

But I need DateTimes to show milliseconds plus.

I can write it OK by changing the culture. But I get a missing Header error on the read.

```
private class TradeData
{
    public string Symbol { get; set; }
    public DateTime utcDT { get; set; }
    public int SignedAmount { get; set; }
    public double MidPrice { get; set; }
    public double BidPrice { get; set; }
    public double AskPrice { get; set; }
}

private static List<TradeData> Trades = new List<TradeData>();

public static void WriteIt()
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(jobDirectoryPath, runName, "TickTraderSim7.csv")))
    using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer))
    {
        var myCI = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
        CultureInfo myCIclone = (CultureInfo)myCI.Clone();
        myCIclone.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        myCIclone.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss.ffffff";
        csv.Configuration.CultureInfo = myCIclone;
        csv.WriteRecords(Trades);
    }
}

public static void ReadIt()
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(jobDirectoryPath, runName, "TickTraderSim7.csv")))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
    {

        var myCI = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
        CultureInfo myCIclone = (CultureInfo)myCI.Clone();
        myCIclone.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        myCIclone.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss.ffffff";
        csv.Configuration.CultureInfo = myCIclone;
        var x = csv.GetRecords<TradeData>();
        Trades = x.Select(f => (TradeData)f).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/76)

Comment: Maybe you should write headers manually.  [Manually Add Header in CsvHelper.CsvWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32443834/manually-add-header-in-csvhelper-csvwriter)

writer.WriteHeader<TradeData>();

Comment: Writing a CSV is really easy and quick, do you really to waste time to modify a libreary behaviour instead of writing a code of like 5 lines?

Comment: What is your connection string?  Is it HDR=YES or HDR=No.  See : https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/  the code is using oledb connection and the header settings is wrong.  Note : oledb connection also has three modes cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text   //(default) or TableDirect, or  StoredProcedure

Comment: @MarcoSalerno I wanted to avoid having to do the parsing myself. But looks like I will have to...

Comment: @ManInMoon Maybe you could give some example data.  Does it not write the header to your file? I made up my own example data and this worked just fine for both writing and reading.  Maybe a culture issue?  My local culture is "en-US".